# CMake unexpected transitive private dependency in shared library

Tags: cmake

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now  based on the various existing SO questions & cmake mailing list archives. However, I can't quite put my finger on it.

I want to build a library named `libA` which will be a shared library that gets consumed by another executable. `libA` has many internal dependencies (`libB`, `libC`, `libD`, ...) which are built/present either as static libraries or cmake's object libraries. `libA` is supposed to contain all the code in order to be a self-consistent shared library that an application can link against without the need to propagate the internal dependencies.

`libA` is being built like this:

```
add_library(libA-objs OBJECT ${HEADERS_PUBLIC} ${HEADERS_PRIVATE} ${SOURCES_PRIVATE})
target_compile_options(libA-objs
    PRIVATE
        -o1
        -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
        -Wl,--whole-archive
)
target_link_libraries(libA-objs
   PRIVATE
       libB
       libC
       libD
)

...

# Build static library
add_library(libA-static STATIC)
target_link_libraries(libA-static PUBLIC libA-objs)

# Build shared library
add_library(libA-shared SHARED)
target_link_libraries(libA-shared PUBLIC libA-objs)
```

I am properly installing `libA` on the system. I also have everything working to export `libA` in a way that a consuming application can just use `find_package()`.

The application consuming `libA-shared` is a shared library itself (a plugin for a 3rd-party application):

```
find_package(libA REQUIRED)

add_library(myplugin SHARED)
target_link_libraries(myplugin
    PRIVATE
        libA::libA-shared
)
```

Upon trying to build, the linker complains about not being able to find/resolve/link `libB`, `libC` and `libD`.
I checked the targets configuration file generated by cmake when installing the exported targets (the scripts that a consuming application pulls in via `find_package()`) and I see that `libA-shared` contains references to `libB`, `libC` and `libD` in the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` as `LINK_ONLY`.

Given that `libA-objs` links to the internal dependencies as `PRIVATE` and given that I am building a shared library (executable!) together with including the whole dependency archives I would have assumed for this to just work.
I do not understand why the internal dependencies show up in the linking commands of a consuming executable as they are marked as `PRIVATE` within the `libA-objs` target.

How do I solve this?

I am using CMake 3.15, GCC 9.2 and would like this to also work with clang 8.0.

Comment: I put the comment because I am not entirely sure. PRIVATE linking implies that API of your libB/C/D libs is not available through libA (like include dirs), but since your libA is a SHARED library, it still needs the libB/C/D to be present. If you `ldd` your libA, you should see sth linke `libB.so => PATH_TO_THIS_LIB`; Then this line `add_library(libA-static STATIC)` doesn't look correct, because there should either be some sources for the new library, or INTERFACE keyword;

Comment: The API of `libB/C/D` is not available through `libA`. `libA` provides a common abstraction layer to hide the API of `libB/C/D` so this is exactly what I want. You seem to indicate that this is not possible with a shared library? Why? I just don't understand why the PRIVATE entries of `target_link_libraries()` gets propagated to the consumer.
As far as I know the way I build the static library is legit as it consumes the object library `libA-objs` which contains the corresponding object files. This is really just creating the archive. I don't currently have any use for `libA-static` anyway.

Comment: Include `libB/C/D` inside the shared library. `I just don't understand why the PRIVATE entries of target_link_libraries() gets propagated to the consumer.` - because that what linking is about. You have to propagate object files and link them when building the "consumer".

Comment: "Include libB/C/D inside the shared library" -> That's what I am trying to accomplish ;-)
Regarding the propagation: `libA` would be the consumer of `libB/C/D`. So why not link `libB/C/D` directly into `libA`? There are no reference to `libB/C/D` anywhere in `libA`'s API (header files). A consumer of `libA` should simply not see the internal dependencies on `libB/C/D`. I fail to understand why this would not be possible.

Comment: OK, actually I reproduced your problem. Indeed CMake tried to link libB to final executable, even though libA linked with libB statically before. [Link](https://pastebin.com/DXTC2DBF) if you need, and let me know if this is exactly your issue (make VERBOSE=1 will show exact linker commands).

Comment: What you pasted is exactly matching my scenario except for the fact that `libA` should be built as a shared library. There's no surprise that the linker will need to link both `libA` and `libB` into the final executable as static libraries are just archives of unlinked objects. What I would expect is that when taking your example and changing `libA` to be `SHARED` that linking the executable `xxx` would not need to link against `libB` too as it should be completely contained in `libA` as it's only used internally.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann This should just work. Shared libraries successfully hide dependencies to static libraries, as you expected. I just tried to reproduce your problem and was unable to do so, I always end up linking against `libA` only, `libB` and `libC` never show up to clients of `libA` for me. There is something going on in your build that you are not telling us about that messes things up here. Try finding a minimal complete reproducer and we can have a look again.